# Cannot POST /register.php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PHP PDO and was trying to do a simple check. When a user signs up through the website, I want the code to check if the username or email has been used before and if it hasn't it will record the information to SQL. When I do a sign up, the page "Cannot POST /register.php" appears. This is my code:

**HTML** (signup.html)

```
<body>
     <div class="square">
        <div class="form">
    <form name ="myForm" onsubmit="return letterCheck()" form method="POST" action="register.php">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <label for="fname"> First Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"> <br>
        <div class= "error" id="notification"></div><br>

        <label for="lname"> Last Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"> <br>
        <div class= "error" id="notification2"></div><br>

        <label for="email"> E-mail: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"> <br>
        <div class= "error" id="notification3"></div><br>

        <label for="uName"> Username: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="uName" name="uName"> <br>
        <div class= "error" id="notification4"></div><br>

        <label for="pword"> Password: </label><br>
        <input type="password" id="pword" name="pword"> <br>
        <div class= "error" id="notification5"></div><br>


            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="signin.html"><input class="button" type="button" value="Sign In"></a> 
                
                <br>

                <div class="right">
                    <input class ="button" id = "submitButton" type="submit" value="Register" style="float:right;"> <br> 
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

**PHP** (register.php)

```
<?php

$host     = "localhost";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$db       = "accountinfo";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    if( $conn != null ) {
        echo "sucessfully connected";
    }
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    // echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    http_error("500 Internal Server Error\n\n" . "There was a SQL error:\n\n" . $e->getMessage());
}

class runSql {

    function runQuery( $query, $conn ) {
        try {
            $q = $conn->prepare($query);
            $q->execute();
            $results = $q->fetchAll();
            $q->closeCursor();

            return $results;
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            http_error("500 Internal Server Error\n\n" . "There was a SQL error:\n\n" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

function http_error( $message ) {
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    die($message);
}

if( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {
    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lastname  = $_POST['lname'];
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    $userName  = $_POST['uName'];
    $password  = $_POST['pword'];

    $sql_u = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $res_u = mysqli_query($db, $sql_u);
    if( mysqli_num_rows($res_u) > 0 ) {
        $name_error = "Sorry... username already taken";
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO signups (fname, lname, Email, password)
            VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$userName', '$password')";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$servername` is not defined so the connection will always fail, same with `$dbname`. This likely means error reporting is off or not being used.

Comment: Is this an experiment or production code?   Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, storing plain text passwords, and is all around very insecure.

Comment: `mysqli_query` doesn't work with PDO and `$db` is just a string, not a connection... looks like a lot of things are off here

Answer (score 0):

You should change :

```
$host     = "localhost";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$db       = "accountinfo";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,$password);
```

to

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
```